# remove the first line of a csv file under windows using cmd command

Tags: csv, cmd, window

I need to remove the first line of a csv file under

> windows

using

> cmd

command
The file size is around **1GB**

Comment: Fine. And what is your specific question? What research have you done? Hint: if the CSV file contains lines shorter than about 8190 bytes/characters, you could use [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), together with its `skip` option; do not use [`more +1`](http://ss64.com/nt/more.html), because this causes troubles with files with huge files...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract N lines from file using single windows command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932722/extract-n-lines-from-file-using-single-windows-command)

Answer (score -1):

Using CMD for such large file sizes is not the most efficient. 
Also, there is no direct command that lets us edit files on the go (such as `vi` in linux).

You can, however, **exclude the first X lines from a file & copy it to a new file** using:

```
more +X [file_containing data] > [file_to_export_data_to]
```

**Source**: [Extract N lines from file using single windows command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932722/extract-n-lines-from-file-using-single-windows-command)