# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 125: invalid start byte in R with Reticulate

Tags: r, pandas, reticulate

Good morning guys, 
I was writing a small script to manage the data in R, but, I don't understand why, when I import an huge csv (3.5 gb) file in R, it doesn't work. 
To solve this problem quickly I decide to use `pandas` with `reticulate`.

```
#Package from python
pd<-import("pandas", as="pd")
#leggo il file csv con pandas
pd$read_csv("C:\\Users\\Befrancesco\\Desktop\\X_dataset\\x_file_name.csv, error_bad_lines= FALSE, encoding = "utf-8" )
```

R returns me this type of error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 105: invalid start byte
```

Where I wronge?

Thank you in advance for oyour answer.

Francesco

Comment: Could be there's an unreadable character in your input csv in position 105. Have you looked at some of your input data? If your file is very big, you can try something like this in your Windows PowerShell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836282/5269252

Comment: @meenaparam Thank you for your answer. 
I'd like to know if padas has a option that it is able to skip the wronge lines. :)

Comment: You're already using the `error_bad_lines` parameter but that isn't helping here. Could your `encoding` be something else here? Try this answer and the one below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python

Comment: Thank you so much! :) It works!
The solution is in the encoding ="ISO-8859-1"

Comment: Excellent, glad that has solved your problem. I'll put something in the answer box just so that we can mark this question off as closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that your encoding isn't UTF-8. Try some of the other encodings, such as ISO-8859-1 in your `read_csv` call e.g.

```
pd$read_csv("C:\\Users\\Befrancesco\\Desktop\\X_dataset\\x_file_name.csv, error_bad_lines= FALSE, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

See this answer for more on different encodings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172249/5269252